# Automatically reload Div and get a variable for usage

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i use a ajax refresh like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#refresh_technik").load('refresh/technik.php');
   }, 1000);
}); 
</script>
```

I have a dashboard, in my Dashboard i include the top_navigation.php and the div "refresh_id" is within the top_navigation.php.

The refresh/technik.php looks like:

```
$db_3s = new Database("3s");

$anzahl_stoerungen = $db_3s->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM 3s_stoerungen WHERE status = 'open' ");    
$stoerungen_gesamt_aktuell = $anzahl_stoerungen->getRowCount();

echo $stoerungen_gesamt_aktuell;
```

In my top_navigation.php i can see on the right top the value from $stoerungen_gesamt_aktuell. It works fine.

But now i will do some other php stuff with the $stoerungen_gesamt_aktuell on the dashboard.php. But it's not possible! The $stoerungen_gesamt_aktuell is empty! It's also not possible to use the variable within the top_navigation.php.

Greetings

Dennis

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to use the value of `$stoerungen_gesamt_aktuell` after it is loaded via your ajax request, other locations of the page, not just the `"#refresh_technik"` div. You cannot continue to use a PHP variable, that you loaded through ajax, on the `dashboard.php` page, as if it were part of the page itself. However, you can load the value into a JavaScript variable, and then use javacript to reuse it on the page. I recommend that instead of using the `.load()` function of jQuery, you actually do a full ajax request with `$.get()`. Then store the result of that value in a javascript variable, then, use the javascript variable elsewhere on the page, after it is loaded. Something like this looks about right:

```
function reuse_my_value(val) {
  $('#refresh_technik').text(val);
  $('#some-other-location').text(val);
  // do stuff with val variable
}

// shortcut for $(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
  $.get('refresh/technik.php', function(r) {
    reuse_my_value(r);
  }, 'text');
});
```

Hopefully this will get you what you need. Let me know if I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. You understand it right. But i think i made a mistake with your code or i misunderstood it.

Now i take your code and combine it with mine, i think there is my mistake, or?

My main problem was, i  try to write a little ajax, that inform the user about a new malfunction. Another user write a new malfunction into the database.

I found a code and it works for me:

```
var old_count = <?php echo $_SESSION["anzahl_technische_stoerungen"] ?>;

setInterval(function(){    
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "refresh/technik.php",
    success : function(data){
        if (data > old_count) {
                $.notification( 
        { 
                    title: "Error notification",
                    content: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.",
                    error: true,
                    showTime: true,
                    border: true        
        }
    );
        old_count = data;
        }
    }
});
},1000);
```

My basic idea was:

1) The user log in to the system, a session will be start with the actual number of malfunctions. 
2) The update function checks all new malfunctions and if there is a new one, the div will be reload and on the mainsite a php script compare the to variables. 
3) The session variable will be unset every 5 minutes and make a new variable.

It was not possible to use the variable from the ajax request to comapre it with the session variable.

BUT NOW!!!!

I found the code above. It works for me and it solves my main problem.

But the Session variable (var old_count) only renew when the user reload the page. I think there will help your script.

The old_count renew all 5 minutes, and the refresh/technik.php renew all minute.